# Cursor moves at the end of text box after updating the first character to upper case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Tried many ways to fix the issue, but badly none of them worked. I tried updating the first character of the input string to upper case in a textbox, this working fine, but the cursor moves at the end of textbox after editing the first character.

Here are my snippets.

```
  const textOnChange = (e) => {
    const value = capitalizeFirstString(e.target.value)
    setTitle(value);
  };

  const capitalizeFirstString = (str) => {
    return str && str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
  };
```

Tried adding refs and manage to set the cursor position, but unfortunately the solutions tried are not working as expected.

My goal is to convert the first character into upper case after editing the string.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain the caret's position before the change by save the current `selectionStart` in a state, and setting it in a `useEffect` with the [setSelectionRange()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange) input method after each update:

```js
const { useState, useRef, useEffect } = React;

const capitalizeFirstString = str => str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
  
const Demo = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [cPos, setCPos] = useState(0);
  const ref = useRef();
  
  const textOnChange = (e) => {
    const value = capitalizeFirstString(e.target.value)
    
    setTitle(value);
    setCPos(e.target.selectionStart);
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.setSelectionRange(cPos, cPos);
  }, [cPos]);
  
  return (
    <input 
      value={title} 
      onChange={textOnChange} 
      ref={ref} />
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Demo />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```